# Correctly outputting JSON with php?

Tags: php, json

New to working with JSON.  I have the following XML results.  I'd like to offer the same results but in JSON format when requested.  My data is coming from a mySQL array.

My problem comes in when I try to have multiple nodes of the same name.  Take my XML result for instance:

```
<results>
    <result>
        <item_id>1</item_id>
    </result>
    <result>
        <item_id>50</item_id>
    </result>
    <result>
        <item_id>50433</item_id>
    </result>
    <result>
        <item_id>3</item_id>
    </result>
</results>
```

If I simply do something like the following in PHP, my data keeps overwriting eachother.

```
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    $json["results"]["result"]["item_id"] = $value;
}
```

It gives me only one line of result which is the last item_id of 3.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: It looks like you keep setting the value of the same node in your loop.

Comment: Keeping the xmlish array levels is super unnatural. Slash `result` and `item_id` at the very least, if there's no further content.

Comment: thanks mario.. actually a ton of content in each <result>; just cut it out for an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting your value in your loop because you're not putting it into an array.

```
$json["results"]["result"]["item_id"] = $value;
```

should be

```
$json["results"]["result"]["item_id"][] = $value;
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to specify an index each time through the loop, or no? i.e. `$json["results"]["result"]["item_id"][$i]`

Comment: No. It will automatically increment as with any numeric key array.